# I cannot install Apache Netbeans IDE with TemurinJDK 11 installed

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I cannot install Apache Netbeans IDE with TemurinJDK 11 installed. I receive the following msg:

> Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer. JDK 8 or newer is required for installing the NetBeans IDE. Make sure that the JDK is properly installed and run installer again . You can specify valid JDK location using -javahome installer argument .

Need help .

Comment: To help clarify the issue: (a) What version of NetBeans are you trying to install? (b) How are you installing NetBeans? (c) What OS are you using? (d) Have you verified your Java installation (e.g. by running `java -version` at the command line)? (e) Did you try the `-javahome` installer argument mentioned in the error message? (f) Have you researched other questions on S.O. which cover similar issues - and what have you tried for yourself (so we don't repeat suggestions)? All these details (and maybe more) may help you to get a better, faster answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting JAVA_HOME on the system variables, here are steps obtained from the url [How to Set Java Path in Windows and Linux?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-java-path-in-windows-and-linux/)

1. Go to the Search box and type advanced system settings in it. Now click on the View advanced system settings.
2. Select the Advanced tab and then click environment variables.
3. In the system, variables click the New button. Now in the edit system variable, type variable name as JAVA_HOME and variable path as the path where the JDK folder is saved and click on OK button Usually the path of the JDK file will be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version_of_jdk.
4. Now in the system variables go to the path and click the edit button.
5. Click the New button.
6. Now add the following path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Then retry the installation.